# trying to run a common jquery function meant for both jquery UI tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have jQuery tabs and a function which basically runs on both tabs, so trying to separate that if one tab is active and not hidden and it has some elements inside that, the function should work only for that,

My confusion is how do I make it separate, I tried using `getIndex`, getting title or trying to check the tab status which is active, but I am lost.

So checking if I can get the status of the active like True/False

```
function getActive() {
    return $("#tabs ul li.ui-state-active");;
}
```

rather than playing with tabs.

I decided to check that if the ui-active is present but I am getting an error

> curTab is undefined

```
function x($obj) {
    var $curTab = $obj.closest('fieldset').attr('class');

    if($curTab.hasClass('ui-tabs-hide')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would also be good to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Your function seems to be trying to returning a list, beside the double ;; there shouldn't be any problem, but you need to provide more of your code as what have you provided to this point is no use for any.